# How to tell if middleware contains a Run()?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

Is there any way to tell in ASP.NET Core if any given middleware will contain a `Run()` call which will stop the pipeline? It seems that `UseMvc()` is one big one, but I am not even certain about that, I just keep reading that it needs to go at the end, I assume it is because it contains a call to `Run()`.

Perhaps there is a way to generate a visualisation of the pipeline for all middleware currently in use, showing which one contains the `Run()` call?

Comment: 1. Not only `Run()`, but also `MapWhen()` will terminate the process. Also, anyone could create a custom middleware that doesn't invoke the `next` delegate and then cause to a terminate. 2. It's the duty of middleware to determine whether there's a need to to call `next`. There's no built-in way to visualize the pipeline except you read the document/source code. That's because all the middlewares will be built into a single final delegate at startup time. When there's an incoming message, the final delegate will be used to process requests.

Comment: [too long to post as a single one comment] As a programmer, we know what will be done by the middlewares, we know the time when it branches, and we know the time it terminates that's because we write the code. But the program won't know it until it actually runs just because the final delegate is built at startup time.

Comment: @itminus Thanks, any reason you didn't post that as an answer?

Comment: Since the question is "how to tell". My reply, which only describes how the middleware works, seems not answer the question itself. So I post it as a comment.

Comment: @itminus Your answer seems to be, "There is no sure way to tell, beyond reading documentation on each specific piece of middleware."

Comment: Yes. Although we should be able to make it by a static/dynamic code analysis in theory, but it requires really hard work. Reading the document/source code should be a much easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There is no sure way to tell, beyond reading documentation on each specific piece of middleware.

quoting itminus in the comments on my question:

1. Not only Run(), but also MapWhen() will terminate the process. Also, anyone could create a custom middleware that doesn't invoke the next delegate and then cause to a terminate.
2. It's the duty of middleware to determine whether there's a need to to call next. There's no built-in way to visualize the pipeline except you read the document/source code. That's because all the middlewares will be built into a single final delegate at startup time. When there's an incoming message, the final delegate will be used to process requests. As a programmer, we know what will be done by the middlewares, we know the time when it branches, and we know the time it terminates that's because we write the code. But the program won't know it until it actually runs just because the final delegate is built at startup time.